# Running queries created by Kibana using Java API?

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch

Is it feasible to run queries created by Kibana using Java API?
I mean get a ready queries from Kibana dashboards that are created by users dynamically, and pass it like a parameter in Java ?

this is an example of a query  coming from Kibana dashboards :

```
{
 "size": 0,
 "query": {
 "filtered": {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "query": "*"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1274879129857,
              "lte": 1432645529858
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
          "must_not": []
        }
       }
     }
 },
   "aggs": {
    "3": {
    "terms": {
    "field": "ruleid",
    "size": 20,
    "order": {
      "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like this: srb.setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(" \"match_all\": {}"), filter));

Comment: This should be possible using the Elasticsearch Search API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/master/java-search.html